# Differences between executing in the Emulator or in the real Device

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

I know there are many things that the emulator has not way to do and you have to test your app in a real device, like for example test how your app works with no wifi connection (unless you unplugged the ethernet of your machine).

But my question is, could be bigger differences between the execution of the same app in the real device than in the emulator? Because my app is crashing or working really bad in a Samsung Omnia 7 but the same deploy in the emulator works really fine....

**Does anybody experiment the same behaviour?**

Answer (score 2):

You could run into speed issues: the phone is coping with more events than the emulator (I am not receiving real calls and am not syncing with some email back-end on the simulator)

The phone could have a different set of service packs/upgrades.

The phone has real hardware that might be broken.

The phone might have less real memory.

The phone might have several other apps running.

These things are different between real phones too so that is why you should always test your app on several real phones of different types/brands.

Answer (score 2):

- The emulator performance is based on your computer's speed, so it's
  most likely going to be faster than the phone. Not sure what's
  happening with your app as there isn't any detail, but one
  possibility is that you're loading or saving a large file when the
  app is (re)opened and the app can't load it on the phone within `10 seconds`
  causing the app to automatically exit.
- Your app might also be using too much memory (it has to be below
  `90mb` to pass Marketplace testing, although the app won't exit if you go past it unless your app takes more than the OS thinks it should).
- Another option might be that your phone's locale settings are
  different to the emulator's and you haven't adjusted your code to
  support certain cultures which could be throwing an exception.

Answer (score 1):

The emulator uses the resources provided by your computer. Your apps performance will always be better on the emulator than in the device. You should debug from the device to see why the app crashes, other than that the performance is because of the difference in the available resources.